# How to call String[][] in R using rjava

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am preparing an R wrapper for a java code that I didn't write myself (and in fact I don't know java). I am trying to use rJava for the first time and I am struggling to get the .jcall right.

Here is an extract of the java code for which I write a wrapper:

```
public class Model4R{
```

[...cut...]

```
public String[][] runModel(String dir, String initFileName, String[] variableNames, int numSims) throws Exception {
```

[...cut...]

dir and initFileName are character strings for the directory and file name with initial conditions, variable names is a list of character strings that I would write like this in R: c("var1", "var2", "var3", ...) and can be of length from one to five. Finally, numSim is an integer.

Here is my tentative R code for a wrapper function:

```
runmodel <- function(dir, inFile, varNames, numSim){

hjw <- .jnew("Model4R")

out <- .jcall(hjw, "[[Ljava/lang/String", "runModel", as.character(dir), as.character(inFile), as.vector(varNames), as.integer(numSim))

return(out)
```

}

The error in R is:

```
Error in .jcall(hjw, "[[Ljava/lang/String", "runModel", as.character(dir),
: method runModel with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)[[Ljava/lang/String not found
```

I suspect that the JNI type isn't correct for String[][]. Anyhow, any help that could direct me towards a solution would be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of the JNI for String[][] - it should be `"[[Ljava/lang/String;"`. Also, I think you need to call `.jarray` instead of `as.vector` on `varNames`. The R error is telling you that rJava thinks the class of the third argument is `Ljava/lang/String;` instead of `[Ljava/lang/String;`.

Comment: I've solved it in the meantime with help from the rJava author, but thanks, indeed these were exactly the points that I was missing!

Comment: @franchong: Great to hear you got it working! :) In future, remember you can [answer your own questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). This helps other users with the same problem, and stops potential answerers from duplicating your effort. Welcome to Stack Overflow - I hope you enjoy the site!